# Sufficient statistic function for $f(x) = \theta x^{-2}, \; \; 0 < \theta \leq x < \infty$

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

**Exercise :**

> Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with probability density function $f(x) = \theta x^{-2}, \; \; 0 < \theta \leq x < \infty$, where $\theta$ unknown parameter.
>
> (i) Check if the given distribution belongs to the Exponential Family of Distributions.
>
> (ii) Find a sufficient statistic function $T$ of $\theta$.

**Attempt :**

(i) It is :

It does not belong to the Exponential Family of Distributions, since the support of $X$ depends on $\theta$.

(ii) To try and find a sufficient statistic function, we must write $p(x|\theta)$ in the form of $G(t,\theta)H(x)$.

Thus :

$$p(x|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \theta x_i^{-2} \mathbb{I}_{[\theta, + \infty]}(x_i)$$

**How should I continue to find a sufficient statistic function from here on?**